ld: framework 'FirebaseCore' not found
I have a kmm app that uses Firebase.
In the android project, the packages are found in the build process, the problem is with the ios app.
When I try to build the iOS app, I receive the error:
> Task :shared:checkSandboxAndWriteProtection
> Task :shared:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors SKIPPED
> Task :shared:compileKotlinIosArm64 UP-TO-DATE
> Task :shared:xcodeVersion UP-TO-DATE

> Task :shared:linkDebugFrameworkIosArm64 FAILED
warning: Cannot infer a bundle ID from packages of source files and exported dependencies, use the bundle name instead: shared. Please specify the bundle ID explicitly using the -Xbinary=bundleId=<id> compiler flag.
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld invocation reported errors
Please try to disable compiler caches and rerun the build. To disable compiler caches, add the following line to the gradle.properties file in the project's root directory:
    
    kotlin.native.cacheKind.iosArm64=none
    
Also, consider filing an issue with full Gradle log here: https://kotl.in/issue
The /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld command returned non-zero exit code: 1.
output:
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lcompression', '-ldl', '-lz'
ld: framework 'FirebaseCore' not found
error: Compilation finished with errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared:linkDebugFrameworkIosArm64'.
> Compilation finished with errors

In my app I have the latest versions of Kotlin and Firebase:
kotlin {
    androidTarget()
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        //iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }

plugins{
    kotlin("android").version("2.0.21").apply(false)
    kotlin("multiplatform").version("2.0.21").apply(false)
}

sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-firestore:2.1.0")
                implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-common:2.1.0")
                implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-auth:2.1.0")
                implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-functions:2.1.0")
            }
        }

The FirebaseCore is present in link Binary with Libraries from Xcode:

Also in Frameworks targets:

Also I use the last version of Firebase SDK iOS 11.6.0:

Also when I import FirebaseCore in swift for my app, everything goes as expected, I can even go inside the FirebaseCore import and check their code.
Version of gradle:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.9-bin.zip

What could be the problem of:
ld: framework 'FirebaseCore' not found
